# How to retrieve facebook username from graphobject?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to retrieve facebook username from facebook API but i am getting errors.

I have tried the following code

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
echo $user=$response->getName();
```

the code  is inspiring my to retrieving  username from facebook and running succesfull.
     When I execute in browser data display like this

```
 $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

echo = $graphObject;
```

data shown like this I know as GraphObject
        Facebook\GraphObject Object

```
    (
    [backingData:protected] => Array
            (
            [id] => 54665634
            [first_name] => somePerson
            [gender] => male
            [last_name] => SomePerson
            [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/983427658473566/
            [locale] => id_ID
            [name] => SomePerson
            [timezone] => 7
            [updated_time] => 2015-05-13T14:47:40+0000
            [verified] => 1
        )

)
```

this is my problem

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookResponse::getName() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hacking\fbtest.php on line 39

so how can i solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use method `getProperty` on graph object

```
$request = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
print_r($graphObject->getProperty('name'));
```

will print SomePerson in your case . Or just use `asArray` on graph object this will retun all information from private `backingData` variable as array.

You can take a look on GraphObject.php file and you will see what other methods you can use:

https://github.com/packetcode/fblogin-basic/blob/master/lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php

Comment: I just know graphObject after using facebook API , what data type graphObject ? , where I can learn it . I mean is it just about the facebook API unlike chapter,array,json in php .

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand you. More information about graphobject you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0

Comment: I mean, you know that there are many chapter in php such as variabel and then  procedural, object oriented programming etc. 
where are facebook API located?

Answer (score 0):

The new v2 Graph API no longer returns Facebook usernames, so this can't be done any more. Check the [current docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) for the fields you'll be able to access.